# How to get close price for normal candles in Pine script while using Heikin Ashi candles?

Tags: pine-script

I want to plot difference between current Heikin Ashi (HA) close price and real close price (on normal candles) in Pine script 3.

Seems like it can work if I use normal candles on chart but if I use Heikin Ashi, I get HA close price instead of normal one.

```
HAclose = security(heikinashi(tickerid), period, close)
NormalClose = security(tickerid, period, close)

plot(HAclose, offset=1, show_last=1)
plot(NormalClose, offset=1, show_last=1)
```

The code above is expected to draw two lines in front of last candle, showing HA close and normal close. It does if chart is set to normal candles, but on HA candles those have same value -- HA close. Same if I use just `close`.

Is there a way to explicitly address price on normal candles?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to refer normal candle prices when you are using a different kind of candlestick type. I have gone through the reference manual and couldn't find a built-in variable for that.

Comment: I was able to get real price by hardcoding tickerid into security: ``security("BITMEX:ETHUSD", period, close)``. Maybe HA changes ``tickerid`` somehow? I could parse it back maybe but not sure if Pine is capable of it. Maybe construct ``tickerid`` out of ``ticker`` and something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading the comments I was able to *hack* it using [syminfo.prefix](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#var_syminfo%7Bdot%7Dprefix) and [ticker](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#var_ticker)

```js
//@version=3
study("Actual price for HA candles") //, overlay=false)
selected_interval = input(title="Interval", defval="D", type=resolution)
// selected_interval = tostring(interval)

actual_close = plot(security(syminfo.prefix + ":" + ticker, selected_interval, close), color=green)
HA_close = plot(security(tickerid, selected_interval, close), color=red)

fill(actual_close, HA_close, color=color(purple,0))
```

I tried to make the interval automatic as well, but I was not successful since the [interval](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#var_interval) variable only returns interval multiplier, so it behaved strangely on some timeframes.

I tested this on BITMEX:ETHUSD daily chart - if you have a look at 12th June 2019 with HA candles selected you can see that the actual close is 263.05 (green number) while the HA close is 254.00 (red number).

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. For Pine Script 5, use ticker.new(...) like so
`float regular_close = request.security(ticker.new(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker), "", close)`. Note: empty string for timeframe is current timeframe.

Answer (score 2):

```
realPrice = request.security(ticker.new(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker), timeframe.period, close)
```

v5

Edit Explanation:

When on a Heikin Ashi chart the `close` price is Heikin Ashi calculation and not the close for normal candles. The [`security`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request%7Bdot%7Dsecurity) function returns the close for any ticker and any timeframe.

Example: Get the close on a AAPL chart on timeframe 5

```
realPrice = request.security("AAPL", "5", close)
```

Instead of typing in "AAPL" get the current ticker with:

```
currentTicker = ticker.new(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker)
```

Instead of typing in "5" get the current timeframe with:

```
currentTimeframe = timeframe.period
```

Final:

```
realPrice = request.security(currentTicker, currentTimeframe, close)
```

Comment: Could you explain some of your code, to make it easier to understand for future readers?

Comment: @SinhNguyen i added some explanation, if there is anything confusing or still in question feel free to ask. :)