Getting high low close values of normal candle in hieken ashi chart
I want to get real open high close price in my indicator code to display percentage of real open to high in hieken ashi candle chart in a label. I tried some codes from stackoverflow but not giving right percentage. Is anyone knows solution

Please update the description with more information such as what you've tried. show some code in whatever language you're working in.

If you're working in PineScript - this thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639829/how-to-get-close-price-for-normal-candles-in-pine-script-while-using-heikin-ashi

//Open = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"7",open)
//Close = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"7",close)
//High = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"7",high)
t = ticker.new(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker, session.extended)
[Open, High, Low, Close] = request.security(t, timeframe.period, [open, high, low, close])
if close[2]<open[2] and close[1]>open[1]
percentage = ((High-Open)/Open)*100
mylabel=label.new(bar_index,high,text=str.tostring(percentage,"#.##") ,style=label.style_label_down,textalign =text.align_center ,force_overlay=true)

Linked answer has worked

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

can anyone tell me pine script code for chartink condition= abs(number20) greater than daily rsi2
